# How to un-CreateFile

Tags: winapi, file-io, error-handling

Let us say that i am writing data to a file handle:

```
hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERICREAD | GENERICWRITE, 0, null, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
//[snip error check]
try
{
   if (!WriteFile(hFile, buffer, count, ref bytesWritten, null))
       throw new Win32Exception(GetLastError());
}
finally
{
   CloseHandle();
}
```

If my write of data failed, i want the file to be **deleted** when i close the handle. I.e.: i want the file to be **"un-CreatFile'd"**.

---

i've tried the obvious, delete the file if there was a problem:

```
hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERICREAD | GENERICWRITE, 0, null, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
//[snip error check]
try
{
   try
   {
      if (!WriteFile(hFile, buffer, count, ref bytesWritten, null))
          throw new Win32Exception(GetLastError());
   }
   finally
   {
      CloseHandle();
   }
}
catch
{
   DeleteFile(filename);
   throw;
}
```

There are two problems with that approach:

1. There's a race condition, where someone could open my file after i close it, but before i delete it
2. i might have permission to **Create** a file, but not the **Delete** it.

What i would like is a way to ***retroactively*** specify:

> `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`: The file is to be deleted immediately after all of its handles are closed, which includes the specified handle and any other open or duplicated handles.

to the file that i have open.

i created the file! Surely i can uncreate it! All because i forgot to specify a flag before-hand?

Comment: Interesting question. It would make sense to be able to retrospectively add that flag. What you describe sounds to me like you should be using a temporary file and rename it once you've successfully written to it so nothing else will open it "before you delete it".

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593768/is-there-a-way-to-remove-file-flag-delete-on-close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all versions of Windows, you can

1. Specify `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` when opening the file originally.
2. Open it a second time, specifying `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`
3. Close the second handle.
4. The file will be deleted when all handles are closed.

This is explained in the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` description in the documentation for `CreateFile`:

> The file is to be deleted immediately **after all of its handles are closed**, which includes the specified handle and any **other open or duplicated handles**.
>   If there are existing open handles to a file, the call fails unless they were all opened with the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` share mode.

---

If the automatic deletion isn't good enough, you could look into Transactional NTFS, putting file creation and all writes into a transaction, and then rolling it back if necessary.

Comment: Nice answer, although this change would mean that anybody with privileges could delete the file out from under his program. Would skipping the FILE_SHARE_DELETE and instead simply closing the first handle first work?

Comment: @HerrJoebob: Maybe, but only if nothing is actively using the first handle.

Comment: Wait... closing the first handle first?  No, that wouldn't work, you're back to the original race condition.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows Vista and newer, this could be done using [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows 2003 server or Vista or higher, [ReOpenFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you're looking for. It allows you to specify a new 'flags' parameter for the reopened handle. Shame it's apparently not available on XP.

Comment: This is actually the same as "Open it a second time" as specified in my answer.  The advantage of `ReOpenFile` is that the file is identified by the existing open handle, rather than by path.